# Getting UnKnownHostException while deploying app to kubernetes from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-groovy, azure-aks

I am getting below error in Jenkins while deploying to kubernetes cluster:

> ERROR: ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: java.net.UnknownHostException: **.azmk8s.io: Name or service not known
>   hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tried to deploy with below jenkins pipeline snippet:

```
kubernetesDeploy(
            configs: 'deploymentFile.yaml',
            kubeconfigId: 'Kubeconfig',
            enableConfigSubstitution: true
        )
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Have you deployed AKS private cluster ([document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters))? If so, jenkins needs to be in the private network to access k8s cluster.

If this is not private cluster, check the network setting of jenkins to see it is able to connect to internet. also check the DNS setting of the jenkins box as the error which you have shard is DNS error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. both are in private network. since jenkins is not able to reach kubernetes cluster i suspect there has to be some additional configurations that needs to be done at jenkins to allow access to kubernetes cluster right? I do not have admin access so I am unable to check in detail. any help in this direction would help.

Comment: Can you log into jenkins box and try accessing the k8s cluster from that network? I suspect the jenkins and k8s cluster being in different private network and does not have connectivity between these subnets. .

Comment: I am able to curl the kubernetes cluster through sh commands from jenkins pipeline but when i try deployment with plugin, it throws UnKnownHostException.

Comment: Which plugin are you using in jenkins for deployment? Try deploying a sample yaml file directly through kubectl from jenkins host to rule out the network related issue. If that works, then there is something wrong with the plugin.

Comment: I am using kubernetesdeploy plugin. The Jenkins Admin has not installed kubectl command on server. so i have to use this plugin only.

Comment: Can we provide proxy server details as part of kubeconfig ?